# Where did my material / texture buttons go?

Tags: texturing, materials, interface

Something happened when editing a Blender scene that caused me to lose the whole texture properties window and most of the materials window as well. They all appear as normal when starting a new file, but for this file they seem to be permanently gone.

This is what the window looks like now:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you changed the rendering engine to Cycles accidentally.  In the Info window (aka the main menu), click the drop-down list which reads “Cycles Render” and change it to “Blender Render” (or “Blender Game” if you are using the Blender game engine).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 11):

When using the *Cycles render engine*, the textures tab will only show if you have a texture added to your material.

If there's no texture properties, then you can enable it by **assigning a texture** of any kind to the color input of your shader.

1. Click the dot for the **Color Input** of your shader
2. Select a **texture** of any kind
3. The **texture properties** will now be shown

[image: Assigning A Texture To The Color Channel]
[image: Cycle's Texture Panel]

Answer (score 2):

There is also a bug that causes the texture tab to disappear, regardless of whether or not you have a texture applied. You must restart blender to have it reappear.

Comment: This is actually extremely important to note.  Many will think it's their node setups or render engine choice.