# Add an image to an object

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to put a 2D image on a 3D object in Blender. How do I do that?

I have found the "textures" tab in the "properties" window, but I can't figure out what to do with it.

Preferably, I would like to click and drag an image off my desktop right onto the object.

Comment: I cannot change the color of the material to an image even after changing the render mode to "Cycles" and creating a new material with glossy finish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you tagged this with unity you will want to use Blender Render and not cycles, this needs to be selected at the top of the window.

[image]

In the texture settings, check that you are showing material textures (the centre button above the texture list), click the new texture button, ensure Type is Image or movie, then open your image file. This should leave you with something like -

[image]

By default you won't see the effect of the image straight away in the 3dview, you can switch the viewport shading to material or rendered to see the result.

[image]

There is also an addon called "import images as planes" that you can enable, which will create a plane and apply the image you select as it's material.

Comment: Grea! Thanks especially for the viewport instruction, I wasn't sure I was doing it right until I used that.

Answer (score 13):

First off you can just drag an image right onto the object to add the image.
Now before you get too excited, there are some things you have to do to get it to work before it will render like that.
[image: drag image to add]

First, you have to be using the Blender Internal render engine for the drag and drop to add the image to the object.
To actually get the texture to render you have to use the material, and the texture panel. (more on why it "no clicky-worky? no typy-worky?" later.)

[My answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18131/2217) explains how to set up a material and texture for the BI. Only difference is you have already imported the image, so instead of clicking on the *Open* button, click on the drop down button to use a image already in blender.
[image: add image button]

---

**Now for cycles**

[My answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18162/2217) explains the procedure for using images in cycles. Just know that you drag the image in to the node editor, not on to the object.

Now to your "no clicky-worky" problem, I think that stems from the different render engins, cycles and the blender internal. See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/577/2217) for help on that.

Comment: Wow! Why isn't this the accepted answer? The actual "accepted" answer barely even does what the question asks for. Thank you very much, this saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Joehot200 glad I cold help. Thanks for the comment.