# How can I convert a downloaded image as a texture into Blender 2.78?

Tags: import, image

I have put together a small library of various texture images from the internet, i.e., rusted iron, broken concrete, etc. I want to use them in Blender. Most images are .jpg. What do I need to do? Bear in mind I am a blender noobie.

Comment: Please see how to do texturing in BLENDER INTERNAL RENDER: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/add-a-image-to-an-object and CYCLES: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/how-are-texture-maps-imported-into-blender

Comment: Just two different tutorial resources. The term you are searching for is materials and textures. Blender Guru
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOKHwx1VCdgnxwbjyb9Iu1g Gleb Alexandrov
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVA3cYOgsTN4hs3v7pjne7w

Comment: Blender can load images, usually to use them as textures to be applied to objects, but sometimes also for displacement, or manual painting, projection painting... reference images... what you need to do with those textures?