# Texture not being displayed on object mode but it does appear on texture paint

Tags: materials, texture-painting

Why my texture is pink as if it were not assigned at all but in texture paint there's the UV texture I'm currently working on?

When exporting my model there is no texture. In the past I used to be able to see the textured model but now it just shows a pink mesh.

I think it could be some issue with the material because I don't see the texture there on the material. Only on the texture tab I see the texture I'm painting in texture paint mode. I'm not sure how to link them back again.

Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: adding blend file and removing detail view of texture settings because not enough reputation for more than two links.

[image]

Comment: It's on Blender render. Changing it to cycles doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Yes, I'm making sure the image is saved and I also checked the path to make sure that it's found by Blender and the file does exist. I tried creating a new material and now at least the painted texture appears wrapping the preview sphere but the model is still pink as if it couldn't find the texture at all.

Comment: If the image *is* saved on the disk then its source has to be Single Image (with the path to the file set up, generally automatically). It used to happen sometimes that it wasn't changed. Try setting image source to Single Image and pointing Blender to the file manually (below the texture datablock, the textbox will appear).

Comment: You mean in texture tab > Image section? I can see it is already set up to the right texture and in Single Image mode. I tried readding the texture there several times but no luck. In materials tab I can only see a data dropdown with the following options "Link, Data, Object" but no way to set a texture there.

Comment: I don't see texture settings, they are hidden on the screenshot. I can see from the left part of the gif in the UV editor that Options shelf there is opened and Source option there is set to Generated below the image datablock name. Change it as well as one in the texture settings.

Comment: I added a new screenshot with my texture settings. I think everything's correct there. Should I check any additional menus?

Comment: I think you shouldn't. Texture shown on the screenshot is not one used for material, it's a brush texture which is written in the top of the properties editor. These are used for things like Displace modifier, stencil brushes etc. while you want it to be a material texture, see [in details](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/add-an-image-to-an-object).

Comment: Yes because I also tried adding it there just for the sake of it in a (clearly flawed) attempt to find the issue, but it was originally set as a material texture and it does show applied to the feedback 3D cube on the materials tab. Updated screenshot with texture settings.

Comment: I just downloaded the blend. The texture is not packed into the blend file so I replaced with a random picture and I don't have your problem. On the gif you added you can see that on the Image menu you have a little '*'. This mean your picture is not saved. Just click on it and save as Image

Comment: The texture image is saved and it's next to the .blend file. The path in Image > Source seems to be correct as well (I double checked and I can find the file on windows explorer). When I set the 3D view to Material/Rendered I can see the texture but on Texture mode it's missing (pink model). Do I need to do some additional operation to pack a file generated by Blender itself into the .blend file?

Comment: Yes you can pack all your files into the blend file with file --> External Data --> Pack All Into .blend file

Comment: I tried that but got error message "Unable to pack file, source path 'PathToDocuments' not found". This happens now also when saving the file. The path exists and the file did get packed because now next to source there's a button I can click to unpack it. Texture is still missing anyway.

Comment: If you have an error while packing it's not a good sign, better save your texture externally, delete it in your blend file, save everything and re-open and reload your texture.

Comment: lucblender, thanks for your help. I triple-checked the paths and even if it was correct, it was missing the file extension for whatever strange reason (file was created within Blender and I definitely didn't delete it because why would I so I'm not sure what caused the file extension not to be appended to the path). Anyways, it's solved. Thanks for your help!