# Can Blender open .DDS files?

Tags: image

I'd like to open some .dds image files in Blender as I've extracted some files from a game and wish to view them...

Does anybody know if it's possible (either by default or through an addon) to open .dds files in Blender? And if so, how to use them?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Blender does open `.dds` files, though Cycles currently has a bug in 2.79 where some `.dds` image textures can't be seen in rendered viewport or in the final image, showing a pink texture instead.

This can be solved by converting the image to another format, like `.png`.

Here's a great answer on how to use an image texture in Cycles: [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8698/47236)

Here's a similar question (and answer) for Blender Internal: [[How to] add an image to an object [in Blender Internal]](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23438/47236)

Comment: Thanks, but this does not really say how to use the .dds's. I clarified the article to include that.

Comment: @Legoman I've updated my answer accordingly. This is a bit too broad to answer directly here so I provided links to their own questions and answers.

Comment: At this moment, the actual answer is "some of them".