# Adding Textures to a Model?

Tags: texturing

How can I add all the texters that should be on the obj soldier model?
When I want to add texture, my whole model stands out. Because of this, I can add only one texture.
[image]So, I threw a photo on where there are a lot of textures, how to add them?

I can’t find the answer, I’ve been suffering for several days.

[image]/LGhYb.jpg

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). That's a lot of textures. Did you get an *.mtl file with your model? That would do most of the work for you.

Comment: Hello! I told the model from here:
 https://p3dm.ru/files/characters/soldier/10217-swat-castle.html
I don’t know how to apply textures to it.

Comment: It seems you'll have to create new materials for your textures first. This thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/111115/78972

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help :(

Comment: Well, this model doesn't contain any *.mtl file. An *.mtl file adds all textures automatically, without it, you'd have to do it manually (looots of work here). I'd look for another model, if I were you :).