# Blender 2.9 Not Displaying DDS textures in viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, 3d-view

I've heard something about Blender not rendering DDS textures in the viewport somewhat. It does seem to be true. Is there not a fix to this?

Comment: Hello, could you rephrase your question so someone who is not familiar with the subject could try to help you out ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a similar issue with .DDS files on a project and apparently all you have to do is convert them to .png. Should be as simple as just renaming the suffix from .dds to .png (but make sure you do this with backup files!)

[Can Blender open .DDS files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111115/can-blender-open-dds-files)

Comment: Renaming the extension will not convert the file. In fact it may lead to applications being unable to open them because of the incorrect file extension doesn't match the mime type. To convert you have to open it with an application that can read the format correctly and save-as as a new format.

Comment: Kind of rude and hasty downvote, did you look at the other thread I linked to at all? I suggested specifically to use back up copies of images... and that comment has been upvoted 5 times. Dont shoot the messenger thanks.

Comment: "*did you look at the other thread I linked to at all?*" Yes, the answer there suggest converting the dds texture to another format, not just changing the extension. That would be the equivalent of pasting a sticker saying Orange Juice over your glass of water and saying you are now drinking orange juice